# WinForm Control to show an Image and text under it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have an application which I developed in C# and Windows Forms.
I googled many times and wasted a lot of time on showing something that exactly looks like the below image

[image: Click To See The Image]

Which control does it use exactly?
Is it something like in the above picture?

Comment: Consider the Listview contorl or a rather simple UserContorl

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 would you have any example ?

Comment: ListView View=Tile.

Comment: A `CustomControl` derived from `Panel` + 2 `Labels` (or +1 `PictureBox` if you don't want to draw the Panel). Add each `CustomControl` you create to a `FlowLayoutPanel` (for automatic placement) or `TableLayoutPanel` (more control on the object disposition, some more code needed). A little more complex with a `ListView`, but it has some predefined layouts that may come in handy, should they be needed.

Comment: I think I recognize it, that was an early sample app for WinRT.  Called UWP these days.  There are multiple ways to do this in Winforms, don't expect an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit manualy but you can create object with code and loops so you can change their property like size text etc.

[image: seems like this]

It's a little bit tough but i don't know how can you make it easyer. I hope it might be helpfull.